# PHP - image src path show broken image

Tags: php, html, directory, constants

I defined a constant:

```
define('ROOT_URL', dirname(__FILE__));
```

I am using it with a second part of a path to call on a png image.

```
 <img src="<?php echo ROOT_URL ?>/images/folder1/logo-black.png" nosend="1" border="none" width="129" height="34" />
```

Image returns broken and my path is not as it should be. (But still when I link it, it shows me a image).

It's like:

```
C:\wamp64\www\email-signatures/images/folder1/logo-black.png"
```

It's with \ and / .

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So I need for it to be ROOT_URL . 'img/imeslike.jpg' as localhost:8080/img/logo-black.png so definign would be easy when imported on server.? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the browser an address like this `C:\wamp64\www\email-signatures/images/folder1/logo-black.png` it will look on the other guys PC for that folder and file. Remember you are passing text (HTML) to a browser on someone elses PC, for the browser to interpret and paint on that other PC's Screen. You need to pass a URL so the browser knows to go to your WebServer for the image.

You could use the whole `http://domain........` but if you just use the relative folder name, even if you move this code to another domain, it should still work just fine.

So assuming the images folder is just below your DocumentRoot try

```
<img src="images/folder1/logo-black.png" nosend="1" border="none" width="129" height="34" />
```

Comment: I want to pass an URL. Is my constant not defined right?  I commented of desired output in a comment above. @RiggsFolly

Comment: You dont need the constant if you use a relative path. The browser will fit the Domain in from where ever the rest of the page came from

Comment: You only really need the whole domain if you are getting something from someone elses site like `http://microsoft.com/something`